# PHP - how to prevent .php files from direct access

Tags: php, .htaccess

i have following folders:

```
mywebsite/en/index.php
mywebsite/en/product/info.php
mywebsite/en/tags/tags.php
mywebsite/en/games/list.php
```

my site is running on friendly url, top mentioned files accessable from following friendly urls

```
mywebsite/en/?pageno=1
mywebsite/en/product/Nike-glove
mywebsite/en/tags/Nike
mywebsite/en/games/ice-sports
```

i have some examples, but nothing work for me like...i want to prevent direct access to .php files..i want to do that with htaccess...can i?

thanks and kind regards

Reelmark

Comment: Why do you store files in webroot if you don't want them to be accessible?

Comment: Put them outside of your document root. It's the safest method. Leave only your main controller script inside the root.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

add 404 page and try following...

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ /[^?\ ]*\.php[/?\ ]
RewriteRule .*\.php$ 404.php [L]
```

Comment: You're really a king!

Comment: This will fail on requests like `/script.php/oops` because your RewriteRule is unnecessarily and erroneously matching on `\.php$`. `RewriteRule .* 404.php [L]` is better as we've already pattern matched the request URI with the RewriteCond, and you can even do `RewriteRule .* [R=404]` to use the same 404 mechanism as any other "unknown resource" making the entire operation transparent.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure exactly sure what you are trying to accomplish, but this will prevent *direct* access of your php files:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /[^\ ]+\.php($|\ )
RewriteRule \.php$ / [F,L]
```

Though I'm guessing you really want to redirect to the friendly urls when accessing the php files directly.

Comment: jon how to prevent file having parameters like "website/tag/tag.php?pno=1"

Comment: @ReelMark where are these links coming from? You can't just magically make arbitrary links into something else. If you are generating them, change how you're generating them, if they're being linked to from elsewhere, redirect with a 301 to where the content really is.

Answer (score 1):

```
<Files ~ "\.php$">
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
</Files>
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution I've settled on is based on [@Fou's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11715525/335880), but I've modified it to handle the case of `/script.php/oops` and opted to rewrite the response code as 404 instead of using a temporary redirect:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ /[^?\ ]*\.php[/?\ ]
RewriteRule .* - [R=404]
```

Answer (score 0):

just add this into your htaccess file... give it a try :) hope it useful

```
RewriteEngine On
IndexIgnore *
```